# Add custom keyboard shortcuts based on terminal language

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to add custom shortcuts for R to my VS code settings. I have set a shortcut for the pipe `|>` operator for editor widows by adding the following to my keyboard shortcut json file.

```json
    {
      "key": "ctrl+shift+m",
      "command": "type",
      "when": "editorLangId == r && editorTextFocus",
      "args": {"text": " |> "}
    }
```

However, this shortcut doesn't apply to the terminal. I think the `when` argument in the above chunk would look something like `terminalLangId == r && terminalTextFocus`. However, those arguments (e.g., `terminalLangId`) don't appear to be actual arguments used by VS code.

Can anyone provide advice on how to set language specific keyboard shortcuts for the terminal in VS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send text to the terminal you use a different command, `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence`.

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+m",
  "command": "type",
  "when": "editorLangId == r && editorTextFocus",
  "args": {"text": " |> "}
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+m",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "when": "terminalFocus",
  // "when": "terminalShellType == r && terminalFocus  // try this
  // "when": "editorLangId == r && terminalFocus",  // maybe you want this?
  "args": {"text": " |> "}
}
```

This will type `|>` in the current editor when it has focus, and if it is an `r` file.  Or, if the terminal has focus, `|>` will be printed there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I cleared my keyboard shortcuts and just added this but wasn't able to get it to work. To be clear, I'm not sure if I'm looking to send text from the editor to the console. In RStudio, the pipe shortcut works in both the editor and the terminal and I'm looking to replicate that experience.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "terminal language" - there is no such concept in vscode.  The text isn't really going from the editor, only from the keybinding.  I edited the answer, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks - that's more like what I was looking for. If there is any way to make the shortcut only apply to the R terminal and not other terminals like bash, I think that'd be a tidy solution, but as it stands your answer resolves my question. Thank you!

Comment: I do see a context key: `terminalShellType` which for me has a value of `gitbash`.  I don't know what the `r` terminal would return here, perhaps just `r`.  I added a when clause to the answer you could try.  If it doesn't work, run the `Inspect Context Keys` command after opening the `Help/Toggle Developer Tools`,  and clear the console.  When you run the `Inspect Context Keys` command, just click anywhere and then look at the console object which should have been added and search for `terminalShellType` and see what it says for a `r` terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"when": "rSessionActive && terminalFocus",` with `"command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",`

```
    {
      "key": "ctrl+shift+m",
      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      "when": "rSessionActive && terminalFocus",
      "args": {"text": " |> "}
    }
```